# runtime error (-2147024770). The specified module could not be found

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    On Error GoTo Err
    MDE.Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database\Report.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    Exit Sub
Err: MsgBox "Database Error: Failed To Connect!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error!"
End Sub
```

I coded this and it worked properly last night, and this morning I moved that folder to try whether it works or not. After I moved it, it shows an error.

> runtime error (-2147024770). The specified module could not be found

I have no idea to solve this error. I have tried to see the doc and nothing helped me out.

Comment: Is the database itself inside the folder that you moved, and did you update the folder path in the Connection string?

Comment: (MDE) is the app Data Environment. Not only the MDE connected to this database. There are some adodc that are connected to that database too. The adodc can connect to the database with the same connection string as the MDE.